# Hazelcast map entry listener does not from Spring

Tags: java, spring, hazelcast, hazelcast-imap

I am trying to configure Hazelcast map to use entry listener using Spring. However, I see that it does not work (events are not coming to the listener).

My entry listener:

```
public class MyMapListener extends EntryAdapter<String, String> implements MapListener{
    @Override
    public void onEntryEvent(EntryEvent<String, String> event) {
        EntryEventType type = event.getEventType();
        System.out.println("Event type: " + type);
    }
}
```

My Spring application context:

```
<hz:hazelcast id="instance">
    <hz:config>
        <hz:group name="dev" password="password"/>
        <hz:properties>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.merge.first.run.delay.seconds">5</hz:property>
            <hz:property name="hazelcast.merge.next.run.delay.seconds">5</hz:property>
        </hz:properties>
        <hz:network port="5705" port-auto-increment="true">
            <hz:join>
                <hz:multicast enabled="true"/>
            </hz:join>
        </hz:network>
        <hz:map name="myMap" >
            <hz:entry-listeners>
                <hz:entry-listener class-name="rw.gov.dgie.bms.hazelcast.listener.map.MyMapListener" include-value="true"/>
                <hz:entry-listener implementation="myMapListener" local="true"/>
            </hz:entry-listeners>
        </hz:map>
    </hz:config>
</hz:hazelcast>

<hz:client id="client">
    <hz:group name="dev" password="password"/>
    <hz:network>
        <hz:member>127.0.0.1:5705</hz:member>
    </hz:network>
</hz:client>

<bean class="rw.gov.dgie.bms.hazelcast.listener.map.MyMapListener" name="myMapListener"/>

<hz:map id="myMap" instance-ref="instance" name="MyMap" lazy-init="false"/>
```

When I add the listener to injected map from Java code, it works fine:

```
@Autowired
private IMap myMap;

myMap.addEntryListener((MapListener)new MyMapListener(), true);
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Are you getting the events from local member? It looks you have configured the listener as local. Can you please try with `<hz:entry-listener implementation="myMapListener" local="false"/>`?

Comment: Even with local="false" events do not come to the listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
<hz:map id="myMap" instance-ref="instance" name="MyMap" lazy-init="false"/>
```

to

```
<hz:map id="myMap" instance-ref="instance" name="myMap" lazy-init="false"/>
```

The `id` is the bean name, the `name` is the map name.

In the top section of the original code, the listener here

```
<hz:map name="myMap">
   <hz:entry-listeners>
```

is added to a map named "*myMap*" and the bean at the bottom references a map named "*MyMap*". So two different maps due to the capitalisation of **M** on one and not the other.